# HBase AsyncProcess warning

Tags: hadoop, hbase

My HBase Get/Put are taking very long time sometimes. When I checked in logs, I see below lines getting printed for very long time. Does anyone knows why it's happening?

> 18/09/25 10:04:43 INFO client.AsyncProcess: #1, waiting for 28 
>   actions to finish on table:

Sometimes, the application is running for half an hour with same message in logs.